# Delimit Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter

Hi I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

**Input**

```
Name        |ID                                    |   Header3
Person 1    |(‘Data’,Date of Birth’,’xyz’,’Friend’)|    1
```

**Expected Output**

```
Name        |Type|Metric       |Code|Relation|Header3
Person 1    |Data|Date of Birth|xyz |Friend  |  1
```

**Code**

```
df = pd.read_csv('Output.csv',header=[0,1,2,3], index_col = [1])
df.columns.name = 'ID'
df.index.name = 'Name'
df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
df.reset_index()
ndf = df.stack(0
pdf = ndf.to_frame()
pdf.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

Comment: so ... what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you have a problem with column ID.
Here is code to get result what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Person 1', 
                     ('Data','Date of Birth','xyz','Friend'), 1]],
                      columns = ['Name','ID','Header3'])

tmp_df = df.ID.apply(pd.Series)
tmp_df.columns = ['Type', 'Metric', 'Code', 'Relation']

df = df.drop(['ID'], 1).join(tmp_df).reindex(['Name',
         'Type', 'Metric', 'Code', 'Relation', 'Header3'], axis=1)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: @ms5573 wellcome. If that enough, you can mark my answer as answer for you question.